# Create specific XML elements programmatically from an XSD file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm developing a generic XML editor and need to be able to programmatically create specific child XML elements from an XSD file, which I can then add to other parent nodes.

Something like this:

[image]

When I right click on the root element "breakfast_menu", a context menu pops up and gives me an option to add a new food element to it. The new food element that is generated needs to have all the sub elements/attributes that are associated with it (name, price, etc ... as defined in the XSD) already added to it. That's the tricky part.

I've played around a bit with XSModel, which enables me to inspect the definition of elements as defined in an XSD file. I'm not quite sure to what extent yet. It's very cumbersome.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this? Ideally, I'd need a library that I can tell which specific child element in an XSD I need generated, and it would produce org.w3c.dom.* objects (or something similar) which I can add to my node tree.

I've seen solutions that produce entire xml files from xsd, but the xml that's produced most often doesn't contain all elements, that is parent elements don't contain child elements for which minOccurs="0" has been defined. It's those child elements I need, though.

Comment: You effectively need to build an intellisense engine, so first you need to figure out where you are in the XML file, then you need to reconcile this with your position in the XSD, then you need to figure out what's possible given your location and state in the XSD. This is further complicated by the xsi:type and substitutionGroups. If you write this from scratch its a big undertaking, I suggest to try to extract some intellisense code from a text based editor and adapt it, or put a few weeks aside and boot up the coffee maker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out about org.apache.xmlbeans.

It's very well documented (in contrast to org.apache.xerces, which was a pain to work with).

I can use xmlbeans's [SchemaType](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaType.html) to extract xml type information from an xsd file and manually create org.w3c.dom.Nodes for my JTable.